# nmcli command for Wifi with MSCHAPv2 on Ubuntu 20.04 server on Raspi

Tags: ubuntu, raspberry-pi, nmcli

My raspberry Pi is on a robot and I don't have (or hope not to be forced to install) any graphical interface. So I want to us nmcli. I've been trying to get the right incantation, maybe someone can save me time.

Our internal wifi network at Brandeis University requires MSCHAPv2 for Phase 2, our domain is brandeis.edu, I know my login identity (which would include the @brandeis.edu) and my password.

What would the command be?

Also previously I had it set up with netplan (where I could also not  figure out the right parameters. So if you know how to configure a netplan .yaml for this situation that would also be so helpful!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried `nmtui`? That is more interactive, but still works over a ssh connection.

Answer (score 2):

You can add the network through:

```
nmcli con add type wifi \
    ifname "INTERFACE_NAME_HERE" \
    ssid "SSID_HERE" \
    wifi-sec.key-mgmt "wpa-eap" \
    802-1x.identity "IDENTITY@brandeis.edu" \
    802-1x.password "PASSWORD_HERE" \
    802-1x.system-ca-certs "yes" \
    802-1x.domain-suffix-match "brandeis.edu" \
    802-1x.eap "peap" \
    802-1x.phase2-auth "mschapv2"
```

Then connect:

```
nmcli dev wifi connect SSID_HERE
```

Comment: I wish I could nominate both as the right answer! You gave me the answer, but Joachim did better, he taught me something new and very useful with which I was able to figure out the answer!